# SQL How to process WHERE = Any

Tags: sql, if-statement, azure-sql-database

For a stock market app I've coded a stored procedure with

```
SELECT [Stockname, Price]
FROM [StocksTable]
WHERE Currency IN [UserDefinedTableOfCurrencyCodes]
```

However, when the user wants to see all prices regardless of Currency it is obviously inefficient to include a WHERE clause at all -- but the only/best way to accomplish this that I can see is to have an IF clause in the stored procedure.

Am I so noob as to be missing a better solution? (note the real app has four different possible WHERE criteria rather than just Currencies so the IF logic might get complicated.  P.S> I realize the IF statement could be webserver or even front side and point to different stored procedures but at this development stage at least prefer to keep control/design in my db).

EDIT/UPDATE:  FYI Apparently SQL Server turns an IN clause into a series of OR clauses.

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Read an excellent article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: Thanks for this reply I read through the link and it was right on topic.  Notably for future readers the link describes pluses and minuses to various strategies but for my purposes suggests using WHERE  (CurrencyID = '@CurrencyID OR '@CurrencyID IS NULL) . . .

Answer (score 4):

If you have any parameter for user wants to see all currency, for example, like `@ShowAllCurrency`, you can change query like this.

```
WHERE (@ShowAllCurrency = 1 
       OR Currency IN [UserDefinedTableOfCurrencyCodes] )
```

If `@ShowAllCurrency == 1` equal true, sql not look for IN part.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need to show all records regardless of currency, then yes, you won't need a WHERE clause for that.
If you write a clause that says WHERE Currency IN ([every currency you have]) then the database *may* just process that in the same way as not having a where clause (from what I understand, but I may be wrong).

Comment: Can anyone confirm this?  It sounds both reasonable and counter-intuitive.

Comment: I'd like others opinions as well. I'd be interested if it's processed differently. How does it seem counter-intuitive? If a WHERE clause includes every possible value, then essentially there is no filtering of rows with a WHERE clause.

Comment: Counter-intuitive (to me) in that the only way such a feature would work would be for the DB logic to do a pre-check for every WHERE clause (i.e. does value = all possible values in table) which would be un-necessary overhead (especially since if I were coding the DB logic I would make the assumption that if there is a WHERE clause it is reasonable to expect it to do something).  Now if you are only referring in your answer to the practical effect of a WHERE value=All possible then of course the output is going to be the same -- but with unnecessary computing overhead.

Comment: That's a good point Mike. I've updated my answer to say that I might not be correct.